# How to compute total score in a multiple choice type exam where each number has its corresponding weight(points)?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an answer key with corresponding points in the database, for example,

```
number  answer   points
  1       A         2
  2       A         3
  3       B         2
  4       B         3
```

Now, when I input and check the student's answers,

```
number  answer
   1      A
   2      A
   3      C
   4      D
```

I want the system to return me the student's score which is 5/10.

My problem is I don't know how to fetch and get the total of these points where the answer key and the student answer match. This is what I've tried so far.

```
for ($i=1; $i<=$num; $i++) {            
$answer = $_POST['answer'][($i+1)-1]; //this is the student answer
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM paper WHERE sy='$sy' and sem='$sem' and test_name='$test_name' and id='$i' and subject='$subject'");
$qry = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$ans = $qry['answer']; //this is the answer key

if ($answer == $ans){
$resultA = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(points) FROM paper WHERE sy='$sy' and sem='$sem' and test_name='$test_name' and id='$i' and answer='$answer' and subject='$subject'");
$qryA = mysql_fetch_array($resultA);
$score = $qry['SUM(points)'];
```

Comment: I've tried to compare the two answers using "if-else" and then querying the points but the score it returns is always zero.

Answer (score 1):

Your schema does not include a student ID, so I have left that out of consideration:

```
select sum(points) as Score
from answerkey k
inner join answers a on k.number = a.number
where k.answer = a.answer
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06699/3)

With student ID, you would do a `GROUP BY` like this:

```
select a.student_id, sum(points) as Score
from answerkey k
left outer join answers a on k.number = a.number
where k.answer = a.answer
group by a.student_id
```

Comment: thanks. actually, I have a student id in the database. i'm new to this and pardon me but i don't understand your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should really show what you have attempted first, and explained your issues... however, couldn't resist the question:

```
SELECT
    SUM(k.Points) As Score 
FROM Answers a 
JOIN AnswerScoreKey k 
ON k.Number = a.Number AND k.Answer = a.Answer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
    test_answer (number, answer, points) AS (VALUES
        (1, 'A', 2),
        (2, 'A', 3),
        (3, 'B', 2),
        (4, 'B', 3)),

    student_answer (number, answer) AS (VALUES
        (1, 'A'),
        (2, 'A'),
        (3, 'C'),
        (4, 'D'))

SELECT
    SUM(ta.points) AS score,
    (SELECT SUM(points) FROM test_answer) AS total_possible_score

FROM student_answer sa

INNER JOIN test_answer ta
    ON sa.number = ta.number
   AND sa.answer = ta.answer;
```

Comment: thank you. but the test answers are to be fetched from the db, not to be included in the code. same with student answers, they are yet to be inputted.

Comment: Yes, of course.  The CTEs are just there so you can run the query and verify that it does what you want, given the example input.  You would start copying from the `SELECT` keyword if you wanted to paste the query somewhere for actual use against real tables.

Comment: thank you. what does "ta" stand for in "ta.points"?

Comment: It's a table alias; see `INNER JOIN test_answer ta`, which performs an inner join against `test_answer` but gives the table the name `ta` within this query, to cut down on the query's verbosity.

Answer (score 0):

A SQL query could do that..

```
SELECT SUM(k.points) AS TOTAL FROM k.key,s.answers WHERE s.answer = k.answer;
```

Where:
k.key is your answer key and s.answers is your student's test.
You can add additional logic to limit it to one.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it! I just changed `[($i+1)-1]` to `[$i-1]`.